# Exporessjs Controller and action names in view files

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I have few routes like.

```
app.get('/help', controllers.static.help);
app.get('/about', controllers.static.about);
app.get('/posts', controllers.posts.index);
```

Under my `layout.ejs` I want to fetch controller and action names and assign to body class. like.

```
<body class="<%= locals.controllerName %>_<%= locals.actionName %>">
```

In my app I have many hundred of such routes and don't want to pass view parameters in each controller action.

Is there any central hook or way to fetch above requirements?

Comment: Nazar, maybe dig it out from the stack trace manually using  `new Error().stack`